# Updating object belongs_to association creates new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Event object with a `belongs_to` association to `location`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location  
end
```

In my Event form I use nested attributes to display the location form. Relevant bit for location form from `events/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :location do |lf| %>  
  <%= f.label 'Location', :class => 'control-label' %>
  <%= lf.text_field :name  %>
  <%= lf.text_field :address %>
<% end %>
```

I create a new Event as follows:

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.build_location
  end
```

However, when I edit the location of this newly created record, the location record does not get edited, instead a new location record gets inserted in the database.

My question is, how do I make sure that upon editing a location (from the parent Event form), it will update the attributes belonging to the location object instead of creating a new Location object.

Comment: quick question location has many events,paste your view code.Do you want location should be created on every event or on creating event location should be selected from existing one

Comment: The user can select locations from a list. If the location is not there yet, it should be created. If it is in the list, only the association should be saved.

Comment: Does your `Location` class have an according `has_many :events` or `has_one :event` in it?

Comment: @rudolph9: no, as the foreign key resides in the Event object

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it was by adding `:update_only => true` to the association. Code for the model becomes:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, :update_only => true  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

Comment: I think the `:update_only` needs to be given to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` instead of `belongs_to`.